# Does Boltzmann's tombstone have "S = k log w" engraved on it?

Tags: history

I heard somewhere that Ludwig Eduard Boltzmann's tombstone has **S = k log w** engraved on it.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Boltzmann) repeats the claim without references:

> The equation for S is engraved on Boltzmann's tombstone at the Vienna Zentralfriedhof — his second grave.

Is this true?

Comment: You may want to see the Physics Nobel laureate [Julian Schwinger's](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/Julian_Schwinger_headstone.JPG) headstone too.

Comment: or Otto Hahn's https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/af/Hahngrab.jpg/576px-Hahngrab.jpg

Comment: Really??? Clicking one link on the Wikipedia-Page to see a picture of the tombstone was too much effort? - I'm voting to close as "trivial". Questions on skeptics should ask to verify a contested or unbelievable claim. - THis is like asking "is the white house really white?"

Comment: Also (maybe the Wikipedia article was edited after this was posted) the image **is** actually on the [Wikipedia article](https://i.imgur.com/4ARUg7z.png) linked itself.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, the grave has the formula, and Wikipedia does have this: [Boltzmann's entropy formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann%27s_entropy_formula)

[image: grave]

Comment: Inarguably one of the greatest tombstones ever.

Comment: @JimmyM. But it gets worse over time ...

Comment: Ow, that joke. o.o

Comment: [Boltzmann was suffering from depression and committed suicide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Boltzmann#Final_years). He spent his last years defending his theory and he was likely thinking about the second law of thermodynamics and entropy, so there's a second meaning to the epitaph...

Comment: This picture is literally the first hit when asking google pictures for "Eduard Boltzmann's tombstone"